# Does there exist an $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ exist such that $e^{e^{A}} - I_n$ is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have one doubt whether an $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ exist such that $e^{e^{A}} - I_n$ is singular?

I think I have to show that 1 is the eigenvalue of  $e^{e^{A}}$ in case answer is yes. But I  am not finding a way to proceed with this idea. I need help with this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What complex numbers $\lambda$ solve $e^\lambda=1$? And next: What complex numbers $\mu$ solve $e^\mu=\lambda$ for one of those values of $\lambda$? Can you arrange for $A$ to have such $\mu$ among their eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly no such $A$ exists when $n=1$. For $n=2$ and $A=\pmatrix{\log(2\pi)&-\pi/2\\ \pi/2&\log(2\pi)}$, we have $e^{e^A}=I$. Therefore a desired $A$ exists for every $n>1$.

Comment: are you sure?  I computed your $e^{e^A}$ using Matlab and got a (numerical) answer that was nowhere near $I$.  It had very large elements and was not even symmetric.

Comment: @StefanSmith I am 100% sure. You have probably called the wrong function. In Matlab, matrix exponential is performed by $\mathtt{expm}$, while $\mathtt{exp}$ is the entrywise exponential function.

Comment: Thanks. Usually in Matlab if you make a reasonable guess how to do something it works.  I incorrectly used "exp".  How did you construct your example?

Comment: @StefanSmith Solve $e^B=I$ and then solve $e^A=B$. In the scalar case, $B=2\pi i$ and $A=\log(2\pi)+i\pi/2$ are two solutions, then $A$ is turned into a 2x2 real Jordan block.

Comment: @user1551 Why is it obvious that one exists for N>2 ? I agree that for any even N you can just construct 2x2 blocks such that the above holds, but what of the odd N?

Comment: @mathreadler Let $A_2$ be a $2\times2$ example and let $M$ be any square matrix of size $n-2$. Then the direct sum $A=A_2\oplus M$ gives an $n\times n$ example.

Comment: For some reason I thought the requirement was $e^{e^{A}} - I = 0$ and not if it was singular. Of course it is enough that one eigenvalue is zero for it to be singular and then it's enough to have one such block.